# Basic Algebra Help - How do I solve for x: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} =100$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need a refresher on basic algebra.

What rule is used to solve for x for: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=100$?

Comment: Square both sides... then....

Comment: Just keep x positive along with the squaring

Answer (score 2):

The main trick for simple algebra is to get $x$ alone at one side of the equation.

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 100 \quad \text{//multiply by} \sqrt{x}
$$
$$1 = 100\sqrt{x} \quad \text{//divide by 100}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{100} = \sqrt{x} \quad \text{//square both sides}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{100^2}=\frac{1}{10000} = \sqrt{x}^2 = x
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.